# Position of the node of a graph relative to an underlying picture

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

In the following code

```
reg = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9fyf.png"];
noeuds = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18};
arcs = {1 <->  2, 1 <->  3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 
       2 <-> 7, 3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 8, 4 <-> 8, 4 <-> 9, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 
       6 <-> 9, 7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 9, 8 <-> 10, 9 <-> 10, 9 <-> 11, 10 <-> 12,
        11 <-> 12};
posom = {{6.5, 10}, {5, 7.9}, {7, 7.7}, {10, 7.7}, {2, 7}, {4, 
        6.2}, {6, 6.2}, {9, 6.2}, {5.5, 4}, {8, 4}, {6.5, 2}, {8.5, 
        2}, {10, 0}, {0.4, 9.35}, {0.3, 8}, {0.3, 7}, {0.3, 6}, {1, 2}};
Overlay[{reg, 
      Graph[noeuds, arcs, VertexCoordinates -> posom, 
       VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02}, VertexLabels -> "Name", 
       ImageSize -> 700]}]
```

I have some difficulties to chose the place of the vertex for two reasons

I have not starting point on the graph to adjust the nodes. Secondly when I change the position of a node the graph is changed. How can I do ?
Here is the picture ?

I wonder if there is a way to have a grid on the picture to position the nodes ?

[image: France]

Comment: Where is `regions.png`?

Comment: Sorry I just realized that the image was lacking. I have edited the post

Comment: I don't very understand why your graph have a edge about `4<->9`,maybe I have missed something..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is **complementary** to Halmir's answer.

After you adjusted the coordinates, you can copy the coordinates and use them as your final result.

In:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9fyf.png"];
noeuds = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 
   18};
arcs = {1 <-> 2, 1 <-> 3, 1 <-> 4, 2 <-> 3, 2 <-> 5, 2 <-> 6, 2 <-> 7,
    3 <-> 4, 3 <-> 8, 4 <-> 8, 4 <-> 9, 5 <-> 6, 6 <-> 7, 6 <-> 9, 
   7 <-> 8, 7 <-> 9, 8 <-> 10, 9 <-> 10, 9 <-> 11, 10 <-> 12, 
   11 <-> 12};
posom = {{6.5, 10}, {5, 7.9}, {7, 7.7}, {10, 7.7}, {2, 7}, {4, 
    6.2}, {6, 6.2}, {9, 6.2}, {5.5, 4}, {8, 4}, {6.5, 2}, {8.5, 
    2}, {10, 0}, {0.4, 9.35}, {0.3, 8}, {0.3, 7}, {0.3, 6}, {1, 2}};
graph[vcs_] := 
 Graph[noeuds, arcs, VertexCoordinates -> vcs, 
  VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
showMap[vcs_] := Show[{img, graph[vcs]}, ImageSize -> 700];
manipulateMap[] := 
 Manipulate[{cs = vcoord; showMap[vcoord]}, {{vcoord, 90 posom}, 
   Locator}]

Dynamic[cs]
manipulateMap[]
```

Out:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Well, maybe you can do some image processing to find center points of each regions but sometimes manual processing could be better (unless you have many cases).

Using Manipulate manually move your node and then by clicking + symbol paste snapshot

```
Manipulate[
 Show[{reg, 
   Graph[noeuds, arcs, VertexCoordinates -> vcoord, 
    VertexSize -> {"Scaled", .02}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]}, 
  ImageSize -> 700], {{vcoord, 90 posom}, Locator}]
```

[image]

```
DynamicModule[{vcoord = {{571.5`, 809.`}, {412.`, 730.`}, {568.5`, 
     707.`}, {755.`, 699.`}, {230.`, 653.`}, {352.5`, 600.`}, {503.`, 
     578.`}, {688.`, 585.`}, {413.5`, 395.`}, {657.5`, 413.`}, {524.`,
      275.`}, {772.5`, 313.`}, {954.`, 129.`}, {56.5`, 835.`}, {33.5`,
      738.`}, {37.5`, 649.`}, {48.5`, 540.`}, {147.5`, 281.`}}}, 
 Show[{reg, 
   Graph[noeuds, arcs, VertexCoordinates -> vcoord, 
    VertexSize -> {"Scaled", 0.02`}, VertexLabels -> "Name"]}, 
  ImageSize -> 700]]
```

Comment: Thanks to all the contributors. Each of your contribution was brillant and usefull.

Answer (score 4):

I know you try to specify the vertices coordinate to get a graph with a adjacent relationshiop.But I want to provide a method to generate such graph by your map image directly.

Firstly,I will remove those texts and small islands by `CommonestFilter`

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9fyf.png"];
imgPro = CommonestFilter[img, 8]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Let's build a image matrix.I mean I will replace every country with a difference integer in this matrix.I don't very content with this step resorted to `DominantColors`,and I hope to know this solution can be improved in furture by others.

```
imgMatrix = IntegerPart[ImageData[ImageAdd @@ MapIndexed[ImageMultiply[#, First[#2]] &, 
        Flatten[Image /@ Values[ComponentMeasurements[#, "Mask"]] & /@ 
        Rest[DominantColors[imgPro,Automatic,"CoverageImage", MinColorDistance -> .1]]]]]];
```

Of course,we can show this matrix by `MatrixPlot`

```
MatrixPlot[imgMatrix, ColorFunction -> Hue,ColorRules -> {0 -> White}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can get the adjacent relation from this matrix by `ComponentMeasurements`

```
adj = ComponentMeasurements[imgMatrix, "Neighbors"]
```

Show the `img` and our graph in following

```
Row[{graph = SimpleGraph[
    Graph[Keys[adj], UndirectedEdge @@@ Flatten[Thread /@ adj]], 
    VertexCoordinates -> ComponentMeasurements[imgMatrix, "Centroid"],
     EdgeStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick], VertexStyle -> Blue, 
    VertexSize -> Medium], Show[img, graph]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It's done automatically!